# What does the following represent in C

Tags: c

```
*(uint64_t*) mFrame->first
```

It's a pointer, structure and then dereferencing?   Seems a bit bit convoluted to me.
And uint64_t is defined under where?

Answer (score 9):

It is casting the result of `mFrame->first` to a pointer to `uint64_t` and dereferencing it. So the end result is that you get a `uint64_t`.

Comment: 5 voted to close, 8 voted as good answer. So the statement unlikely to help future visitors obviously is wrong. Got outvoted.